# How to add slashes between the chars of a string in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, split

I am doing an activity to learn Kotlin where I am completely stuck. I am new to coding and Kotlin so excuse me for my mistakes and lack of knowledge.

This is the description of the activity:

*You need to write a program that prints date and time in a special format. Hours, minutes and seconds are split by a colon, and day, month and year are split by a slash. For example:*

*Sample Input 1:*

```
23 59 59
12 12 2018
```

*Sample Output 1:*

```
23:59:59 12/12/2018
```

I have been trying a lot of different things, but I'm lost. This is the path that I was trying to take:

```
fun main() {
    val time = readLine()?.split("")
    val date = readLine()?.split("")
    
        println("$time $date")
}
```

I know the code is wrong, as I don't know how to do it, I am simply posting the path or idea that I was following. If someone could explain me what I have to do, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to edit your code like this

```
fun main() {
    val time = readLine()?.split(" ")?.joinToString(":") ?: ""
    val date = readLine()?.split(" ")?.joinToString("/") ?: ""
    
    println("$time $date")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It gives me the error now, I'm not sure what I should do 

error: only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type List<String>?
val time = readLine()?.split(" ").joinToString(":")

Comment: @Pauliecode put a ? before .joinToString for null safety

Comment: Forgot null safety check, see edited answer

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Now it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to check if the read line is actually a date you can use `DateTimeFormatter`

```kotlin
private fun parseDate(arg: String) {
    try {
        val timeString = arg.split(" ").take(3).joinToString(":")
        val dateString = arg.split(" ").takeLast(3).joinToString("/")
        val parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        parser.parse("$dateString $timeString")
        println("$dateString $timeString")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("[ERR] - Error parsing argument: $arg")
    }
}
```

```kotlin
fun main() {
   parseDate(readLine())
}
```